# Can't find script insert option in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to add a script to Google Sheets. I watched a tutorial where to add a script one has to follow the path  `Insert>Script`. But I found that there is no script option there. How can I get the solution?

Comment: See _Tools > Script editor..._ in your sheet and add the script.

Answer (score 3):

This is the option you need. It opens the script editor which may have a couple of lines of placeholder code; those can be deleted and replaced by your script.

[image: menu]